# Mapping <C-m> also creates a mapping for <CR>

Tags: key-bindings

I have a custom function and mapping:

```
nmap <C-m> :MyMake<CR>
```

This works as intendeded, the correct function is called etc. But it creates another mapping, running `:nmap` shows that `CR` is now mapped to `:MyMake <CR>` as well.

Any ideas on why this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<CR>` stands for carriage return, and depending on your terminal settings, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> gets you a carriage return. Consider using another key combination. See also:

- [Disable <Esc> but keep <C-[>](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/disable-esc-but-keep-c)
- [How to remap <C-[> on linux](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3907/how-to-remap-c-on-linux)