# Add ^M character in mapping without entering <CR>

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, search

I've run into the problem mentioned [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3961/17964), but in a context in which I don't have an easy alternative that I can think of.

I'm trying to add a mapping to fix bad newline characters in a file. I would generally type: `:%s/^M//g` to remove all of the `^M` characters. My mapping attempt to do this (and save) is as follows:

```
nnoremap <Leader>fix :%s/^M//g<Bar>w<CR>
```

The problem with my mapping is that the `^M` gets automatically converted to `<CR>` and the mapping breaks, of course. I have also tried:

```
nnoremap <Leader>fix :%s/<c-v><c-m>//g<Bar>w<CR>
```

...and that fails as well.

I've noticed that if I leave off the `<CR>` at the end to debug the mapping, I get `//g|w` as the only thing on the command prompt. Ideally, this would be `%s/^M//g|w` to achieve the desired behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match carriage return, `<cr>`, `^M`, ASCII value 13, you should use `\r` in the pattern: `%s/\r//...`.  This is documented at `:help /\r`.

Note that `\r` in the *substitution* part (`:s//<here>/`), rather than in the *pattern* part, has a completely different meaning which is "split the line in two."

Comment: Another token that matches `<CR>` is character class `[:return:]`. So `:s/[[:return:]]//...` ... `\r` is easier to type, obviously (though maybe not easier to remember).